# Obtaining Facebook Page Access Tokens Without Page Ownership

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

Is it possible to generate a page access token for a page that I didn't create?

I have been granted an 'Admin' page role but annoyingly when I go to the Graph API Explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ) The 'Get Token' dropdown does not show the page I need. It only shows pages I have created.

What do I need to do in order to populate the dropdown with the page I didn't create?

Comment: Do you see the page when you request `/me/accounts`?

Comment: That redirects to: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php. However, The 'Use Facebook as' list does show the mentioned page. I have full admin access.

Comment: I meant make that request in Graph API Explorer …

Comment: Ah yes - I do see it in the results. However, if I change the application dropdown to my custom application I cant see the page name in the 'Get Token' dropdown. How do I associate the page with the my custom app? It seems to automatically be associated when I create a page but of course I haven't created the page I need to see.

Comment: If your app has `manage_pages` permission, then you should see all pages you have admin access to in the dropdown, no matter who created them.

Comment: The 'Get Token' dropdown only shows a limited about of page names. If you administer a large amount of pages then not all will be shown. Your initial suggestion of requesting '/me/accounts' when the app is selected does in fact work. It returns the results followed by a 'Next page' link at the bottom. The data i required was on the following page. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Graph API Explorer with an access_token that has `manage_pages` permission and use the call

`page_id?fields=access_token`

[image: Graph API call]